# What are the outer vests/jackets that samurai wear?

Tags: japan, samurai

What are the outer vests/jackets that samurai wear some sort of jacket, what are they called?
[image: image of a man from "Last Samurai" wearing an overtunic]

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: I believe it is a variation of a kami ([Kamishimo](https://www.yamatobudogu.com/products/kamishimo)); or [kataginu](https://www.encyclopedia.com/fashion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/kataginu).  Also check [JapanFashion](http://factsanddetails.com/japan/cat20/sub136/item746.html).

Comment: What is that picture from?

Comment: @GorttheRobot - from _[The Last Samurai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Samurai)_

Answer (score 1):

That outer vest is a “[Jinbaori](https://www.metmuseum.org/art/collection/search/32638)”. Not referring to armour suit.